# How to target all elements on page with class name and round up it's height to a multiple of 32?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to target all elements with a class name and round it's height up to a multiple of 32px using `Math.ciel()`

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('poo').outerHeight();
var h = Math.ceil(x/32)*32;

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('poo');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.height= h + 'vw';
}
```

I'm not very good at writing my own code so this is basically just a thing I patched up together from other code on this website when I was looking for an answer.

The expected result basically is if a div height is '30', the output should change into '32'. '120' to '128', etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to call `Math.ciel` will throw a `TypeError`. What is `leftvar`?

Comment: I mistyped. It's supposed to be Math.ceil() - I also edited the code above which is where I left off before asking for help here :)

Comment: Do you want to round all heights to the **same** multiple of 32px or each element to its nearest multiple of 32px?

Comment: Round each element to a multiple of 32. So if there's two elements each with different heights, those individual elements will round up to the nearest multiple of 32.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array like structure.  Each of the elements in the structure may have an `outerHeight()` method, but the array will not.  So your very first line for defining `x` is an issue.

Comment: Should it be using some form of `$('.myclass')` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent of jQuery's `outerHeight()` is (for your scenario) `.offsetHeight`.

Also, since you want:

> Round each element to a multiple of 32. So if there's two elements each with different heights, those individual elements will round up to the nearest multiple of 32.

You should move the calculation of the height into the loop:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('poo');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var x = elements[i].offsetHeight;
    var h = Math.ceil(x/32)*32;
    elements[i].style.height= h + 'vw';
}
```

```html
<div class="poo one" style="background-color: red;">one</div>

<div class="poo two" style="height: 60px; background-color: blue;" >two</div>
```

jQuery equivalent:

```js
$(".poo").height(function () {
    var x = $(this).outerHeight();
    var h = Math.ceil(x/32)*32;
    return h + 'vw';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="poo one" style="background-color: red;">one</div>

<div class="poo two" style="height: 60px; background-color: blue;" >two</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much! I'm quite impressed as it looks like I was really close to your solution!